# .htaccess: Rewrite only if there is no subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, url-rewriting

With this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

You can make every URL in the site redirect to the URL plus the subdomain `www.` at the beginning.

The problem I am having is that it is giving me some problems with other subdomains, i.e. I wouldn't want blog.domain.com to me redirected too.

So is there any way to do a generic rule to avoid the redirect of anything that already has a subdomain?

Thanks in advance!!

---

I hope the question is clear enough!! I you need any clarification please ask for it!

Comment: What is this ReWriteRule accomplishing? You are directing www.domain.com to www.domain.com...

Comment: @Jason McCreary, No I'm not, it redirects NON www. to www. subdomains! It is actually working :)

Comment: Wildcard dns? If haha.domain.com or www.haha.domain.com does not exist will redirect to www.domain.com?

Comment: @haha I'm not really sure how would I be able to use them but I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [haha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520725/haha) for leading me in the right direction.

I managed to do it through cPanel, I redirected all non www. with a www. subdomain with wildcards.

Sorry, didn't know it was possible to do specifically this.

Thank you for all the answers and comments!!

Answer (score 1):

yes - your regex for the RewriteCond matches on "anything that is not www.domain.com".  If I understand correctly, you want to match only domain.com.

Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

now if someone uses domain.com, they'll be redirected.  For requests that have anything *other* than domain.com, they will not be redirected.  This includes www.domain.com as well as blog.domain.com, as well as dns2.domain.com.

Comment: Just to be clear I would like everything that does NOT already have a subdomain to be redirected to a www. subdomain, is this what you had understood?

Comment: @Akinator, to my knowledge RewriteCond does not check if the URL exists. You would need to hardcode a check for each of your subdomains.

Comment: @Jason McCreary if you have the time :) how would you approach this? i.e. for blog.domain.com

Comment: Correct, `RewriteCond` does not check for existence of a resource at the original or the rewritten URL.  @Akinator - I think I understand your situation correctly. I still like my answer and wouldn't change it.